How to implement dark theme with blazor and bootstrap?
On https://docs.blazorbootstrap.com/ there is a light-dark theme switcher near Github and Twitter links: 
However there is no explanation how to do it. Bootstrap 5 has now support for dark theme if you apply data-bs-theme="dark" attribute to <html> element https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/color-modes/#enable-dark-mode
I tried to make it work in blazor with javascript functions that read and write selected theme to local storage:
function setTheme(theme) {
    localStorage.setItem('theme', theme);
    // set data-bs-theme to the body element
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-bs-theme', theme);
}

function getTheme() {
    console.log("Getting theme: " + localStorage.getItem('theme'));
    return localStorage.getItem('theme');
}

(function() {
    let theme = localStorage.getItem('theme');
    if (theme == null) {
        setTheme('light');
    } else {
        setTheme(theme);
    }
})();

I also have my theme-switching component that uses IJSRuntime to trigger theme change:
@rendermode InteractiveAuto
@inject IJSRuntime Js
<div class="nav-item px-3">
    @if(_theme == "dark")
    {
        <a class="nav-link" @onclick='() => SetTheme("light")'>
            <Icon Class="px-3" Name=IconName.Moon />Light theme
        </a>
    }
    else
    {
        <a class="nav-link" @onclick='() => SetTheme("dark")'>
            <Icon Class="px-3" Name=IconName.Sun />Dark theme
        </a>
    }
</div>

@code {
    private string _theme = "";

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        _theme = await Js.InvokeAsync<string>("getTheme");
    }

    private Task SetTheme(string theme)
    {
        Js.InvokeVoidAsync("setTheme", theme);
        _theme = theme;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

And this works until I try to go to a different page. Then the html element is overwritten and my data-bs-theme attribute is gone and everything becomes light-themed. When I refresh the page however, everything goes to dark theme again because of the immediately invoked function from javascript.
How to implement it properly?

For Blazor Server, the hindrance is that the html tag is root component and must be rendered statically. But if a Singleton service is created to hold and retrieve the theme between navigations.
In App.Razor:


@using BootstrapColourModeDemo.Services @inject IColorModeServices colorService

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-bs-theme="@BSTheme">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <base href="/" />
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="BootstrapColourModeDemo.styles.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.3/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
  <HeadOutlet />
</head>

<body>
  <Routes />
  <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0pUGZvbkm6XF6gxjEnlmuGrJXVbNuzT9qBBavbLwCsOGabYfZo0T0to5eqruptLy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>

@code { public string BSTheme { get; set; } = "light"; protected override void OnInitialized() { BSTheme = colorService.GetColourMode("User1"); base.OnInitialized(); } }



Create the service: ColorModeService


   

 public interface IColorModeServices
    {
        string GetColourMode(string key);
        bool SetColourMode(string key, string mode);
    }
    public class ColorModeServices : IColorModeServices
    {
        private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> _UserColorModes = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();

        public string GetColourMode(string key)
        {
           string mode =string.Empty;
           if ( _UserColorModes.TryGetValue(key, out mode))
            {
                return mode;
            }
           else
            {
                //Did not find
                mode = "light"; //Default mode
            }
           return mode;
        }

        public bool SetColourMode(string key, string mode)
        {
            bool allGood = false;
            if (_UserColorModes.TryAdd(key, mode))
            {
                allGood = true;
                
            }
            else
            {
                allGood =_UserColorModes.TryUpdate(key,mode, _UserColorModes[key]);
            }
            return allGood;
        }
    }



In the Program.cs add a singleton service:


//The service
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IColorModeServices, ColorModeServices>();



Then add code to change the theme using the service


@using BootstrapColourModeDemo.Services
@inject IColorModeServices colorService
@inject NavigationManager navManager

@rendermode InteractiveServer

@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home - Color Mode</PageTitle>

<h1>Bootstrap Color Mode</h1>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@(() => SetTheme("light"))"> <i class="bi bi-sun"></i> Light</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@(() => SetTheme("dark"))"> <i class="bi bi-moon-stars"></i> Dark</button>


@code {

void SetTheme(string theme)
{
    if (colorService.SetColourMode("User1", theme))
    {
        //To change immediately navidate to start of site
        navManager.NavigateTo("/");
    }
}
}



I recommend that the ColorModeService should be a call to database or another source that has user profile information and store the user's preference for the theme to use for the web site.

private void darkMode()
{
_currentTheme = _isDarkMode ? ApplicationTheme.DefaultTheme : ApplicationTheme.DarkTheme;
_isDarkMode = !_isDarkMode;
}

Upgrade the Blazor.Bootstrap package to version 3.2.0.

NOTE: Remove all the CSS content from the Shared/MainLayout.razor.css file.

Update the MainLayout.razor page as shown below.
Example:
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<BlazorBootstrapLayout StickyHeader="true">
    <HeaderSection>
        <ThemeSwitcher Class="ps-3 ps-lg-2" />
    </HeaderSection>

    <SidebarSection>
        <Sidebar2 Href="/"
                  ImageSrc="https://demos.blazorbootstrap.com/images/logo/logo-white.svg"
                  Title="Blazor Bootstrap"
                  BadgeText="3.3.1"
                  DataProvider="Sidebar2DataProvider"
                  WidthUnit="Unit.Px" />
    </SidebarSection>

    <ContentSection>
        @Body
    </ContentSection>

    <FooterSection>
        Footer links...
    </FooterSection>
</BlazorBootstrapLayout>

@code {
    private IEnumerable<NavItem> navItems = default!;

    private async Task<Sidebar2DataProviderResult> Sidebar2DataProvider(Sidebar2DataProviderRequest request)
    {
        if (navItems is null)
            navItems = GetNavItems();

        return await Task.FromResult(request.ApplyTo(navItems));
    }

    private IEnumerable<NavItem> GetNavItems()
    {
        navItems = new List<NavItem>
                   {
                       new NavItem { Id = "1", Href = "/", IconName = IconName.HouseDoorFill, Text = "Home", Match=NavLinkMatch.All},
                       new NavItem { Id = "2", Href = "/counter", IconName = IconName.PlusSquareFill, Text = "Counter"},
                       new NavItem { Id = "3", Href = "/fetchdata", IconName = IconName.Table, Text = "Fetch Data"},
                   };

        return navItems;
    }
}

Screenshot:

Reference links for more details:

https://docs.blazorbootstrap.com/layout/blazor-server
https://github.com/vikramlearning/blazorbootstrap-starter-templates

